# How to display saved image in iphone gallery to uitableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, nmssh

I am working on a chat application. In that, I have implemented picture uploading and downloading using NMSSH library. Now I am saving the downloaded and uploaded image in app documents file also (saving in iphone gallery too), so that I can display the image after tableview reloading. Is saving images in documents folder is a good method? Is documents folder have any size limit? Is there any way to get the path for the image in gallery?